# SearchController SearchBar Disappears from View

Tags: uisearchbar, xcode8, ios10, uisearchcontroller

I'm developing for iOS 10 using Xcode 8 (Version 8.1 (8B62) to be exact) and I'm trying to develop a view controller that displays a fixed `searchBar` above a `tableView`.  I've got the initial layout, but when I activate the `searchBar`, it disappears completely from my view.

Here is my view controller's view hierarchy:

```
View 
| 
|---- UISearchBar 
| 
|---- UITableView
```

and here is what it looks like:

[image: initial layout]

Now, the problem. Because there is no Interface Builder tool for including a `UISearchController` like there was for `UISearchDisplayController`, I'm adding the `searchBar` programmatically into my interface in my view controller's `viewDidLoad` method and I'm using `searchController.searchBar` to replace a temporary UISearchBar that I use in the storyboard:

```
// attribute to store the searchController
var searchController: UISearchController!

// temporary searchBar from storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var tempSearchBar: UISearchBar!

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.frame = tempSearchBar.frame
    tempSearchBar.removeFromSuperview()
    view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
}
```

When I run the app and activate the `searchBar` object attached to my `searchController`, it disappears from view:

[image: activated searchBar]

The `tableView` also shifts weirdly, but my main focus is getting the `searchBar` to stay within the view. I've tried a few different things to make this work, but I'm having zero luck. Any help is much appreciated.  I just feel like it shouldn't be this difficult to implement. I can do it just fine with a `UISearchDisplayController` object, but those are deprecated and I'm trying to be a good programmer and not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue as you. The problem stems from trying to manually set the frame of your searchBar. Do you need the temp search bar in the storyboard?

To fix this remove the code where you set the frame and connect your tableview from storyboard to your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```